# Image not display and error: PANIC in `/home/anaconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf/noao/bin.linux/x_apextract.e': Write to IPC with no reader

Tags: python, iraf

I am trying to run the

> NTT pessto pipeline

that uses PyRAF. I have everything installed but when I try to test if it works I have two issues, first, the image enviroment opens but the image is never displayed. Then when I try to Edit apertures for the file I am analyzing I get the error:

> PANIC in
>   /home/anaconda2/envs/iraf27/iraf/noao/bin.linux/x_apextract.e':Write
>   to IPC with no reader

I am currently using Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc. and I also have IRAF installed. I am using a astroconda environment that I installed following the legacy software directions from:

> https://astroconda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#legacy-software-stack-with-iraf

I use setuptools so I don't think is an issue of PYTHONPATH

If anyone could help me I would really apreciate it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with IRAF/PyRAF that comes with Ubuntu 18.04:

```
PyRAF 2.1.14 Copyright (c) 2002 AURA
Python 3.6.5rc1 Copyright (c) 2001-2018 Python Software Foundation.
Python/CL command line wrapper
  .help describes executive commands
--> noao
--> twodspec
twodspec/:
 apextract/     longslit/
--> apextract
apextract/:
 apall          apedit          apflatten       apnormalize     apscatter
 apdefault@     apfind          apmask          aprecenter      apsum
 apdemos/       apfit           apnoise         apresize        aptrace
--> apedit dev$pix
Edit apertures for dev$pix? ('yes'):
```

and then a window openes for editing, without the error message. So, I guess this is a bug in your IRAF distribution. You probably should check with the astroconda people.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering @olebole, I uninstalled and reinstalled everything and the problem persists. How do I check with the astroconda people? I am quite new to this and I haven't found an astroconda forum.

Comment: What do you get when you run the four commands shown above (`noao`, `twodspec`, `apextract`, and`apedit dev$pix`)?

Comment: So @olebole, after I run the commands I get **Warning: 827 dev$pix**

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was the matplotlib version.

Comment: For future me, the way to update matplotlib is with PIP